# Counting Young tableaux

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory, combinations, young-tableaux

Let's say we have some shape $\lambda$ and we want to fill this shape with numbers $\{1, .., m\}$ in non-decreasing order in rows and columns. How many such numberings do we have?
I can not find anything about this kind of numbering of Young tableaux.

Comment: What is the exact requirement to the order of numbering and what requirements does $\lambda$ meet?

Comment: I suggest you to google "Robinson-Schensted-Knuth correspondence". There is also a very good book by Fulton on Young tableaux which may be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

The question definitely concerns the number of Standard Young Tableaux from a Young Diagram of shape $\lambda$. The answer is the so-called "hook length formula" we meet in any book on group representations and especially of the symmetric group $S_{n}$. The most important is that this number is the dimension of
the irreducible representation related to this Young Diagram of shape $\lambda$.

see also : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau

Comment: The question it seems to me does not mention that each element occurs exactly once, so it is not standard. Also, there is no mention of strictly increasing along columns, only non-decreasing, so it's not even semistandard Young Tableaux.